# how to copy List item attachment to document library with SharePoint Designer workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, attachments

I have SP Foundation without access to the server local folders, so my only change is through Sharepoint designer as far as I know.
how can I copy a List item attachment to document library with SharePoint Designer workflows?
Note. The document library does not have the same fields as the list.

Answer (score 1):

I could not achieve my goal to copy a list attachment to a document library but on my investigation I discovered how to copy files from one document library to another with Sharepoint service copy.asmx and sharepoint services (see more information on http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

I post below the different functions I created for my testing, as I said they work but not for list attachments as a source.

- uploadFile uses soap CopyIntoItemsLocal to upload.
- uploadFile2 uses SPServices jquery with CopyIntoItemsLocal
- uploadFile3 uses SPServices jquery with CopyIntoItems

Note. I post this because my research didn't help me on my goal but might help someone else.

```
function uploadFile(source,destination)
{
    //source = encodeURI(source);
    //destination = encodeURI(destination);
    var soapEnv =
    ""+
        ""+
            ""+
                "" + source + ""+
                ""+
                    "" + destination + ""+
                ""+
            ""+
        ""+
    "";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://sharepoint.cplis.com/test/CentralisTest/_vti_bin/copy.asmx",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItemsLocal"); },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}

function processResult(xData, status) {
        alert("Uploaded SuccessFully");
    }

function uploadFile2(source,destination)
{   
    //source = encodeURI(source);
    //destination = encodeURI(destination);
    $().SPServices({
            operation: "CopyIntoItemsLocal",
            async: false,
            SourceUrl: source,
            DestinationUrls: [destination], 
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                alert("Status=" + Status + " XML=" + xData.responseXML.xml);        
            }
    }); 
}

function getStream(source) {
    var myStream = "";
    //source = encodeURI(source);
    jQuery().SPServices({
        operation: "GetItem",
        async: false,
        Url: source,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            myStream = jQuery(xData.responseXML).find("Stream").text(); //MSDN: base-64 representation of the retrieved document's binary data.
            alert("myStream: " + myStream);
            } // end completefunc
    }); // end getItem
}

function uploadFile3(source, destination, myStream) {

    source = encodeURI(source);
    //destination = encodeURI(destination);

    jQuery().SPServices({
        operation: "CopyIntoItems",
        async: false,
        SourceUrl: source,
        DestinationUrls: [destination],
        Stream: myStream, //whatever variable you used to store the base64 encoded binary data from the GetItem call
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            alert("Status=" + Status + "\n" + xData.responseText);
            } // end completefunc
    }); // end CopyIntoItems

}
```

Have fun!!