# Copy list item attachment to Document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, custom-list

I have a requirement to copy list item attachment to document library either through workflow or event receiver.

Requirement :

Custom List "A" and Document Library "B" and some workflows(designer workflows) run on item adding(when a user add attachment) on custom list and in that process when the status gets changed in list "A" the attachment should get copied migrated to Document library.

Note : user will upload only one attachment to list item and only that attachment should be copied / migrated to document library.

Please help me and let me know how to go about it.
Either by  workflow or event receiver.
I tried through designer workflow as mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/459f8f64-35e2-46b0-a2b3-58446984e119/copy-list-item-attachment-to-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopment) but getting bad request

Please let know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot copy attachments using SPD Workflow as OOTB, however, you could achieve this using

- Visual Studio workflow.
- Event receiver as mentioned at [Move/Migrate SharePoint List Attachments to Document Library with Created and Modified Date](http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.com/2012/03/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-attachments.html)
- via REST as mentioned at [Using SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow to copy file](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/2/19/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-to-copy-file-via-res.html)
- Check also similar thread [how to copy List item attachment to document library with SharePoint Designer workflows?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68502/how-to-copy-list-item-attachment-to-document-library-with-sharepoint-designer-wo)