# Copy list attachment to document library

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to copy the attachment of list to library through designer workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy attachments using SPD Workflow.

Below link has a similar question. Check the answer in the below link

[Copy list item attachment to Document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191276/copy-list-item-attachment-to-document-library)