# How to make a new list item with an attachment add the attachment to a certain folder within a document library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, attachments, front-end

Good day,

I need to figure out how to do the following:

1. User fills out an infopath form for a custom list. The user has the option to attach an attachment to the form.
2. If the user attaches an attachment when submitting the form, the attachment will automatically be added to a document library in a particular folder.

Is there any way of doing this? I've once again, never heard of such a request. I have the following at my disposal:

SP10 WF
Front end solutions - I have no access to the backend *STRICT*

Currently on SP13 on prem.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to upload the newly added attachment to document library automatically.

You could achieve this via custom workflow or event receiver.

Please refer to：

http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.com/2012/03/movemigrate-sharepoint-list-attachments.html

Similar issue:

[Copy list item attachment to Document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191276/copy-list-item-attachment-to-document-library)